# how to write special characters in an html file?

Tags: javascript, python, html

i'm having troubles writing special characters in javascript from a python code. I explain.

I wanted to have a graphic interface for a python script. I dont have a lot of experience in graphic interfaces with python so I chose to write it in HTML/CSS. To make sure it works in every situations I created a code that writes the html code after processing some informations found in a text file. To put it in a nutshell my code takes already-wrote block of HTML, modifies it, assembles them together, and then writes that new HTML code into a .html file that I can open on my web browser.

Everything works perfectly fine. The problem is that im french and due to this I need to handle special characters like é,è or à. Furthermore in the HTML code I told you about, there's some javascript that use `.innerHTML` to modify the webpage without any loading time. My problem is that when the `innerHTML` code is triggered, the resulting text is this "s�ance" when it should be this "séance" I do think that it's an encoding problem but this happens only in javascript when I use `innerHTML` : if I write it in HTML the same string is fine.

This is what happens exactly to a string in my code:
I read it from a file:

```
file = file.read()
```

Then I write it into an html file:

```
interface = open(r'interface.html','w')
my_text = 'séance'
interface.write("var text = " + my_text + ";")
```

I obviously use then `id_of_an_element.innerHTML(text)`
And so, as explained earlier, when I open the HTML file into a web browser, 'séance' becomes 's�ance'.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `<meta>` tag in your HTML file (To encoding `UTF-8`):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: I already tried this and it didn't worked, I also think it's something like this but changing <meta> tag this way or doing this <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'> with the script tag dont work. If you have anything else i'll try it. Thank you.